# MVC 5 StructureMap StructuremapMvc.Start() return error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I've created a new fresh vanilla MVC 5 .net 4.5 project, and added StructureMap as a Nuget package. Nothing extra added like models or interfaces yet.

All works fine until I add this row in Global.asax.cs:
StructuremapMvc.Start();

I get error that I can't register a module when application have initialized?!

My IoC.cs file looks like this:

```
public static IContainer Initialize() {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                        {
                           x.Scan(scan =>
                                    {
                                        scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                        scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                    });
                        });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
```

Answer (score 3):

> All works fine until I add this row in Global.asax.cs:
> StructuremapMvc.Start(); I get error that I can't register a module
> when application have initialized?!

You don't need to use 'StructuremapMvc.Start();' method because it's been already defined in StructureMapMvc.cs:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(StructuremapMvc), "Start")]
[assembly: ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(StructuremapMvc), "End")]
```